# Execute Mysql query in foreachPartition spark run slow

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I want to execute mysql query inside of foreachparition in spark and get all of query results to a data frame eventually. 
It looks like:

```
var rowAccumulator: RowAccumulator = new RowAccumulator

foreachPartition((p) => {
  val result = MysqlService.getData(query, p)
  rowAccumulator.add(result)
})
```

then convert `rowAccumulator` to a data frame.

However, it runs slow overtime. The first query takes 130ms, the 20th query can take 150000ms, for example. I notice that in MysqlService, I create db session each time and that may be not correct. Is there better way to do that?

Update:
MysqlService is used in different places and we want to make code easy maintain. If it won't perform well, we could apply a different way to execute query, such as using spark jdbc. I am curious what's the reason make this query run slow.

Answer (score 0):

Spark accumulators are not designed for handling large amounts of data. There intended primarily for collecting auxiliary statistics using methods operating in constant memory (like counters).

Using accumulator like this is a less efficient variant of `collect` (not that `collect` is recommended) and doesn't make even remote sense if you

> convert rowAccumulator to a data frame.

Since you use MySQL database you should first take a look at Spark's [JDBC connector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases):

```
spark.read.jdbc(...)
```

and only if you have very special requirements, use custom code. If you do handle conversions directly with `map`

```
rdd.foreachPartition((p) => {
  MysqlService.getData(query, p)
}).map(x => anyRequiredTransformation(x)).toDF
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work well. Foreachpartition return Unit, I can't map the result from each partition.